# Flask logout user when session expires

Tags: python, session, flask, python-3.4, flask-login

Is there a way to execute a logout_user when a session expires? I'm using Flask-Login and have a method that sets permanent session lifetime to 10 minutes.
In my case I would like to logout a user on session expiration.

```py
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=10)
```

Comment: The user should be logged out when the session expires, because Flask-Login uses the session and when the session expired it can't access the information stored there anymore -> the user is not logged in with the session. Or does it not work like you want?

Comment: Well, finaly everything was working fine, the problem was I had a custom decorator that was checking a value in session and forgot to update my code :)